# Can you help me apply a mutex object to this code?

Tags: c++, mutex

Ive been googling mutex tutorials / examples but cant seem to find one for the situation I need (or more likely I did, but just never realized how to apply it to my situation, as I don't fully understand it at the moment).

I have a C++ dll that has 2 callback functions.  The callback functions are called from a 3rd party program.  Each call back function adds information to a global variable (separate global variables).  There are 2 other functions that each use these global variables.

The 3rd party program has many threads, so the call back functions are being called all the time.  The other 2 functions are manually called by the user.  The global variables end up being accessed by 2 things at once and causes a crash.

right now the global variables are in a class like this

```
 class Global
{
public:
static CString &  get_allscores() {  static CString get_allscores; return get_allscores; }
static CString &  get_allplayers() {  static CString allplayers; return allplayers; }
};
```

Could someone show me a quick example on how to use mutex with 2 functions that are both accessing one of those global variables ?

Thanks

EDIT:

What about a situation like this

```
CString allchat; //global variable

void function1()
{
    allchat += "test";
}

void function2()
{
    cout << allchat;
}
```

if those functions were being called by many threads repeatedly and out of order, can I add a mutex object to make it multi thread friendly?

so far my plan was to create a mutex with no owner when the program launches.. and then when each function is called itll take ownership and release it at the end of the function.  is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Unless you want to embrace [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) you should be asking for multi-threaded programming books, not how to plug a mutex in a random piece of code. There's no place in your code to put a mutex.

Comment: The use for a mutex would be to lock your code that modifies your global variables.  The code you are showing just does reads, so it isn't useful.  You need to add more details about how your globals are written and read.

Comment: I didnt bother adding the other functions after I explained them, but the callback functions add info to the variables.  The other 2 functions I mention only read them.

Comment: Also regarding your post Daniel, I am in a weird situation, I want to learn and fully understand it but this is the only time I will need it (this is just a hobby).  I do understand mutex a bit right now, if I was shown or even explained how to implement it into a similar situation I am pretty sure I could apply it here.

Comment: I would strong recommend having the mutexes around the writes to your variables.  You probably want to hide them and only allow them to be accessed by setter methods and place them mutexes there.

Comment: TJD, do I only have to lock code thats writing to the global variable?
not reading?  if so, would a solution be to have a mutex for each callback function  and use WaitForSingleObject at the start of the function, and then release it at the end?

Comment: MartyE, I wrote my previous comment before I seen yours.  Are we saying the same thing?

Comment: When one thread writes to a location in memory at the same time that another thread reads from that location or writes to that location you have a data race and the behavior of the code is undefined. Whenever a thread is writing to a location in memory, any other code that reads or writes to that memory has to be blocked out of it. With the two functions in the sample code this is not possible, because they expose the strings to whoever wants them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PeteBecker
EDIT: I removed my reply from here and put it in OP at bottom, since I couldnt format it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the EDITed part of the answer: yes, if these are the only functions that access the global data, adding a mutex lock to both functions will make the code thread safe. The danger, of course, is forgetting, in the course of developing and maintaining the code, that this global data has to be protected with a mutex. Of course, the solution to that problem is to take the code as written and wrap it in a class, so that `allchat` is a private member, adding a mutex to the class, and using the mutex from any member functions that access `allchat`.

Comment: Thanks again Pete, no real danger with updating because this is just a small dll used to transfer data from 1 source to another with these functions, itll basically never change after this :).